# Why My Django Code Is Not Going To Else Part?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here Is My views.py Where I written User Login Code And The Promblem I'm Facing Is That The Code Is Working Properly For Authenticating User But When User Enter Wrong Credential then I Want User To Take Him/Her To Register Page But I'm Unable To Take It To Register Page
Please Help Me Thorugh This And Let Me Know Where I'm Doing Mistake

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fm = AuthenticationForm(request=request,data=request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            uname = fm.cleaned_data['username']
            pword = fm.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=uname,password=pword)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/')
    else:
        fm = AuthenticationForm(request)
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':fm})
```

Here Are My urls.py

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index),
    path('register/',views.user_register,name='user_register'),
    path('login/',views.user_login,name='user_login'),
    path('profile/',views.user_profile,name='user_profile'),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not handle when the form is invalid (no else statement for `if fm.is_valid():`). Try using the following:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fm = AuthenticationForm(request=request,data=request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            uname = fm.cleaned_data['username']
            pword = fm.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=uname,password=pword)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/')
    else:
        fm = AuthenticationForm(request)
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':fm})
```